# Updated FragmentStatePagerAdapter does not refresh Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an Activity, with two fragments. Currently designed for portrait mode, where one fragment shows up at a time only. I have ViewPager and Actionbar in the app.

First(main) fragment has a button. On click of this, I need to update text box, or a graphview on the other fragment.

I have gone through a number of articles and threads on this, but the last mile connectivity seems to be missing. Here are some details of  my current standing:

- I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter
- Currently overriding getItemPosition to POSITION_NONE. I plan to optimize this later.
- Fragment to fragment communication is via the Activity, through an interface

Problem is that on button click, the new value I am sending via the PageAdapter does not seem to be passing through to the Fragment.

Adapter:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public String graphLink = "Last 24 Hours";

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentMain();
            args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(FragmentMain.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentGraph();
            args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(FragmentGraph.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            args.putString(FragmentGraph.linkGraph, graphLink);
            break;
        }
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

On clicking button on main fragment, i am getting the updated value till the activity in the listener method. There then I am trying to do the below:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter sa = (SectionsPagerAdapter) mViewPager
                .getAdapter();
        sa.graphLink = link;
        sa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(sa);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

This SHOULD have been updating the public variable in the graph fragment. That variable SHOULD have been used to update the textfield etc. during its creation. But this last part is not working, because the graphLink doesn't seem to be passing through.

Here is a snippet of the main parts of Graph fragment of mine:

```
 public class FragmentGraph extends Fragment {

    public static final String linkGraph = "Graph heading";

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

TextView graphHeader = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphHead);
graphHeader.setText(linkGraph);
}
}
```

What am I missing? Looks to me I am doing something dumb in the last leg.
is this even the correct approach to be updating the fragment from another fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my dumb mistake. It was the static final variable causing the issue. I changed that to a private variable, exposed by a getter/setter and all is working perfectly now.

Comment: why would static variables be a problem?

Comment: I got the same problem. You only have one final static variable which is **linkGraph**. That could not be the problem. Can you explain which variable cause the problem?